# Three columns layout and media query

Tags: html, css, layout, media-queries

I'm trying get a 3 columns layout, with fixed width float divs on the left/right and a flexible paragraph in the middle, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/kzde0aqx/10/):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="w_left"></div>
  <div class="w_right"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
</div>
```

And i want to apply a Media Query (@media screen AND (max-width: 800px)) so the box on the right go under the box on the left and the paragraph, ie: next line. The paragraph should fill the freed space.

Considering the 3 columns layout tutorials indicate to put the flexible content after the floated elements and apply an overflow property, i don't understand how to do it since the paragraph is the last tag.

Any help welcome, including a new approach of the situation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Run the code snippet

```css
.w_left,
.w_right,
p
{
  display: table-cell;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table; 
}

.w_left {
  width: 180px;
  background: #aafed6;
}
.w_right {
  width: 180px;
  background: #aafed6;
}

p {
  background: #e8f6fe;
  width: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
  .wrapper,.w_left,.w_right,p{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="w_left">LETT</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum ...<br/>
    Lorem ipsum ...<br/>
    Lorem ipsum ...<br/>
  </p>
  <div class="w_right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I used float solution, the condition "(@media screen AND (max-width: 800px)) so the box on the right go under the box on the left and the paragraph" isn't not done